# How to dynamically feed xAxis of a highchart line graph

Tags: javascript, php

i want to load mysql results to highcharts' line graph using json. In the code below, xAxix is manually feed. How can i feed it dynamically from the mysql database? you'll find the php code and the html code too.
Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Highcharts Example</title>

  
 </head>
 <body>
  

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
     
      chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
             chart: {
                 renderTo: 'container',
                 type: 'line',
                 marginRight: 130,
                 marginBottom: 25
             },
             title: {
                 text: 'Revenue vs. Overhead',
                 x: -20 //center
             },
             subtitle: {
                 text: '',
                 x: -20
             },
             xAxis: {
                 categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
             },
             yAxis: {
                 title: {
                     text: 'Amount'
                 },
                 plotLines: [{
                     value: 0,
                     width: 1,
                     color: '#808080'
                 }]
             },
             tooltip: {
                 formatter: function() {
                         return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                         this.x +': '+ this.y;
                 }
             },
             legend: {
                 layout: 'vertical',
                 align: 'right',
                 verticalAlign: 'top',
                 x: -10,
                 y: 100,
                 borderWidth: 0
             },
             series: json
         });
     });
    
    });
    
});
  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

```php
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bdd");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli__connect_error());
}

//mysqli_select_db($con,"bdd");
$query="SELECT revenue FROM projections_sample";
$sth = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$rows = array();
$rows['name'] = 'Revenue';
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($sth)) {
    $rows['data'][] = $r['revenue'];
}
$query2="SELECT overhead FROM projections_sample";
$sth = mysqli_query($con,$query2);
$rows1 = array();
$rows1['name'] = 'Overhead';
while($rr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows1['data'][] = $rr['overhead'];
}

$result = array();
array_push($result,$rows);
array_push($result,$rows1);


print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysqli_free_result($sth);


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just `echo` your JSON code to the xAxis attribute of your chart settings:

```
subtitle: {
    text: '',
    x: -20
},
xAxis: <?php echo json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>,
yAxis: ...
```

Or if you retrive your data with an AJAX request, perform the request before initializing your chart and use the return data the same way.